# Cypress url not changing on click element with no href

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe, cypress

Scenario 1 : on click element having href attribute

when I try to click on element with following html then I am redirected to a new page and the browser URL changes as well

```
<a href="https://www.abc/page1" class="xyz">Page1</a>
```

Scenario 2 : on click angular element not having href attribute

But when I click on element with following html then I am redirected to desired page but the browser url does not changes

```
<label _ngcontent-vnr-c10="">NavigateToNextPage</label>
```

Because of this, Even when the UI content is loaded, Cypress is not able to locate elements of new page.

Can someone help me with resolution of why the URL is not changed but page content is changed ??

Comment: Is there an endpoint requested when clicking on button scenario 2? You could `intercept` the route & wait for it until moving on with UI assertions. Check the `network tab` in the Chrome dev console.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal multiple api's are being hit on click the said button, since the page content is loaded that means the api's have responded. I also added a harcoded wait of almost 5 minutes but still only the content loads but the url does not changes

Comment: Let me ask some questions to understand better. What issue are you having currently? Are your assertions not waiting for the page to load? Or just want to figure out why the `URL` didn't change with visiting the new page?

Comment: both. Assertions does not work as elements are not located on the new page and the page url has not changed too in cypress test runner

Comment: Got it. Can you include Cypress code being used? Screenshots, gift? You can hide sensitive info

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Cypress code is just a simple click cy.get(locatorVal).click() and checking URL of the page. Can not share screenshot here.