# Cypress does not navigate the route by click() on a link

Tags: angular, cypress

**The question in other words:** How to navigate  href link?

**Issue:** Cypress clicks but the route was not changed.

Sometimes the route changes sometimes not! I cannot understand what happens. Even cy.wait(WISH_TIME) antipatterns do not help.

What I test.

HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['my_link_here']" (click)="closeDialog()">some string</a>
```

Cypress test:

```
cy.contains('some string', {timeout: 30000}).should('be.visible').focus().wait(1000).click();
```

Version:
"cypress": "^9.7.0",
"@angular/core": "13.2.5"

I tried so many assertions as `.should('be.visible')` or `.should('be.focused')` after .focus() - no luck!

Also there is no error. Cypress robo clicks but does not go to the new route(Same situation as here: [Cypress url not changing on click element with no href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914862/cypress-url-not-changing-on-click-element-with-no-href))

Comment: cy.contains returns only the first match DOM element containing your string, so there may be other elements on the page matching that.

Comment: @jjhelguero it is not about selector issues - it clicks, dialog window closes, but does not navigate to the route. Updated the description to make the issue clear. Manually it works.

Comment: But your question isn't really reproducible - take a random Angular 13 Stackblitz, Cypress can navigate the routes with just click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! The Guys above were right! I had to add changes to my angular project! My problem was so specific - after some research i faced **extra autoredirecting** in afterClosed event was blocking navigating via **Cypress** robo(could not reproduce manually, could not see extra routing even with { enableTracing: true } looked good), but anyway you can face the same issue in case you use automatic routing on closing dialogs via `.afterClosed()`. Fix is to add your_condition to not redirect once your dialog closes in specific cases:

**YOUR HTML**

```
<a [routerLink]="['my_link_here']" (click)="closeDialog()">some string</a>
```

**Your component:**

```
this.dialogRef.close(your_condition_arg);
```

**Routing component:**

```
.afterClosed().subscribe((your_condition_arg) => {
  if (your_condition_arg) {
   return;
  }
  return this.router.navigate('..'], { relativeTo: this.route }
);
```